# Crontab task doesn't work when I edit crontab by vim instead of "crontab -e" on docker container ubuntu18.04

Tags: docker, cron

Crontab task doesn't work when I edit crontab by vim instead of `"crontab -e"` on docker container `ubuntu18.04`

step 1:
Use docker run a container, the image is `ubuntu18.04` os.

step 2:

```py
vim /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

and Write content to root file as following:

```sh
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
*/1 * * * * . /etc/profile; /bin/sh /test_cron/xx.sh 2>&1
```

step 3:

```sh
cd /
mkdir test_cron 
cd test_cron
```

step 4:
Edit xx.sh in /test_cron/xx.sh, the content as following:

```sh
echo "cron job has start" >> /test_cron/run.log
```

step 5:

```sh
service cron restart
```

step 6:

There is no `run.log` in `/test_cron/`, that’s to say, the crontab task doesn't work. But if I using `"crontab -e"` to open the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` file and don't make anything modify. Just open and close the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`, I can see the `run.log` file in `/test_cron/`, amazing, the crontab task worked. Could you tell me the reason?

Comment: Even though it is not recommended to directly edit the crontab file, this is a great question lead us to understand how cron works and why there is ```-e``` option associated with the crontab tool.

Answer (score 1):

Few points,

1. The `corntab -e` makes sure certain formatting and error tracking to an extent.
2. crontab file should contain one **empty line** at the end.
3. There are certain permission to set to the crontab `chmod 600`

After completing these I could see the manual entry was working. However it is not recommended to directly edit the crontab file and the best practice is to use `crontab -e`

**EDIT:** Actually `emptyline` should be corrected as newline character or % as per the man page

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
>   run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or %
>   character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in
>   the SHELL variable of the cronfile. Percent-signs (%) in the command,
>   unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline
>   characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command
>   as standard input.

Comment: If use vim to generate the /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root，the default chmod is 644, not 600.
Solve this problem as following:
1. use crontab -e to generate empty /var/spool/cron/crontab/root file，to make sure the chomd is 600, and format is right.
2. Use vim or echo append my cron tasks to  /var/spool/cron/crontab/root file, there is no empty line at the end.
3. Start crontab, amazing, my cron tasks worked.

Comment: @836304831 the idea of the empty line is to append a CrLf. Glad to know it worked with you!